# remove apps like Browser

Tags: uninstallation

I got a samsung galaxy note 8, and it came with an app called browser and also Chrome.
Obviously Chrome is better, so how can I remove the generic browser app (or at least hide it)?

The same goes for apps like Email and Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

Samsung seems to provide similar software on its devices, so this procedure from a different Samsung device (Galaxy Tab 3) will probably hold.

Open the Menu > Settings > Application Manager

Use the right-most panel "All", and scroll the list to find the application(s) you want to disable. Click the button to do so (generally labelled "Disable" or "Turn Off", or similar).

You generally cannot uninstall pre-loaded apps without rooting the device.

Answer (score 0):

Go in to settings and chose the application option.
From there you can chose the list with all and find the browser or internett app.
When you press that app you can uninstall it.

Comment: You can also read more about how to do it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952573/android-4-0-disabling-apps-on-the-device

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want to uninstall it. Stock apps cannot be removed unless you root the device, ignoring the app though is much easier.

First, you can remove the so from your home screen and perhaps even from the launcher (only doable on some devices). @wbogacz had shown how for Samsung device.

Second, you'll want to delete the default app setting so that when other apps request to open a page in browser, you'll be launching Chrome instead of the stock browser. You could do this from `Settings > Applications > Manage applications`. Find the Browser app there and choose Clear Defaults. Next time an app launched a browser, choose Chrome and set it to always launch with Chrome.